# C++: How to prevent "potentially uninitialized warning" if im sure its not uninitialized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Im getting this warning even though theres no possibility that it would remain uninitialized. The Visual Studio 2008 compiler fails to detect this.

How do i suppress this warning at this piece of code only?

Comment: Post your code; you may be wrong, or there may be another way to write it so the compiler "figures it out."

Comment: Hmm, i managed to hide the warning by using a function instead of a boolean flag... now the function returns the flag, instead of dozen of if-statements setting the flag on/off. Weird.

Comment: that makes sense, because you're probably now just assigning the function value directly to a variable.  The question is, are you initializing the flag correctly in the function, and/or does the function always return a value?

Comment: yeah it always returns a value, if it didnt, i would get another warning/error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tend to side with the compiler on this one; you probably initialized it in a nested conditional statement which isn't always hit. But if you really insist on ignoring the warning, you can use the appropriate [#pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(VS.80).aspx) directive with the warning number.

Comment: Ah, thanks, although i got the code working now by altering its way of doing things.

Comment: Anytime. For future reference: if you do something like 'int x; if (condition) x = 3; else if (anotherCondition) x = 4;' x may still be un-initialized at this point and the compiler will warn you. You could solve this by adding an 'else' catch-all, or by starting out with 'int x = 0;' or an acceptable default.

Comment: Note that - at least for simple types like int and double - the optimiser should be able to remove the unnecessary "int x = 0" step anyway if it does see all branches overwriting it, so there's very little downside (except that it's slightly misleading noise for the programmer understanding the code).